# Log4j2 properties | monitorInterval not working

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am using log4j 2.4 and trying to convert `log4j2.xml` to `log4j.properties`, however `monitorInterval property` doesn't seem to be working with log4j2.properties.

- status = trace
- name=PropertiesConfig
- property.filename = logs
- appenders = console, file
- monitorInterval=10

though `log4j2` following documentation 
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties

clearly stats that

> Properties configuration files support the advertiser,
>   monitorInterval, name, packages, shutdownHook, status

any changes in property file doesn't leads to reloading of logging configuration. On the contrary, it seems to be perfectly working in `xml format`

`<Configuration status="TRACE" monitorInterval="5">`

where whenever I do make any changes in .xml my log4j configuration is picked up and is verified via following log.

```
2016-06-17 14:43:17,267 Thread-5 DEBUG Reconfiguration started for context 1198108795 (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@86be70a)
2016-06-17 14:43:17,268 Thread-5 DEBUG Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.

2016-06-17 14:43:17,273 Thread-5 DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/userx/Desktop/logs/log4j2_prod.xml]
```

I also tried to upgrade Log4j version to 2.5 but still observe same behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add to Ralph's answer, this was fixed in Log4j 2.6. The corresponding ticket is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1263

Please use Log4j-2.6.1 or later.

Comment: I'm using 2.8.2 and still have the problem. xml is working fine, but .properties monitorinterval has no effect.

Comment: The first thing to do is always upgrade to the latest version to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Please raise a ticket for that on the log4j JIRA issue tracker.

Comment: Please try with the latest version of log4j. If that doesn’t work please raise a ticket on the log4j issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug that has been fixed. I would suggest updating the latest log4j release.

Comment: Are their any reference which tells that in which version bug exists and on which it has been fixed. Any links would be helpful. problem is in there are some method changes in log4j 2.6 which are not compatible with our framework.

Comment: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/changes-report.html and http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/jira-report.html#a1.0-alpha1

Comment: Which changes are not compatible with your framework and in what way?